# Choosing Single Row from multiple rows - Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a requirement below to choose latest status.

Table 1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

Results Expected:

[image]

Below is the logic we need.

```
    SELECT
        Table1.ID,
       ,CASE WHEN (Table1.hub=Table2.hub) THEN Table2.Status ELSE NULL END AS Original_Status
       ,CASE WHEN (Table1.hub<>Table2.hub AND Table2.Status like 'Found%' ) THEN Table2.hub ELSE NULL END AS Derived_Hub
       ,CASE WHEN (Table1.hub<>Table2.hub AND Table2.Status like 'Found%' ) THEN Table2.Status ELSE NULL END AS Derived_Status
from
    Table1 
Join Table2
    ON (Table1.ID=Table2.ID)
```

With this code, I am getting 3 rows. If I put max in the above case statements, I am getting Hub3 instead of Hub2.

Could you please let me know how I can merge everything into single row. Please note that I want to show latest found Status from Table 2 even if there are 2 hubs with found status.

Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: What's your Teradata release?

Comment: Version is 14.10.07.05

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to join into Table 2 twice. The first time, much like you are doing here, but using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on both `id` and `hub`. Then the second time on a derived version of table2 where you only select the top 1 records when sorted by timestamp in descending order:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.hub as "Original Hub"
    t2.status as "Original Hub Status",
    t3.hub as "Found Hub",
    t3.status as "Found Hub Status"
FROM
    Table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON
        t1.id = t2.id AND 
        t1.hub = t2.hub
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            --Select a hub with the same id, that doesn't share the same hub number
            --Only choose the top record when sorted by timestamp in descending order           
            SELECT TOP 1 id, hub, status
            FROM table2
            WHERE t1.hub <> table2.hub
            ORDER BY TimeStamp Desc
        ) t3 ON
        t1.id = t3.id
```

That subquery that has alias `t3` is using a correlated subquery by referencing the `t1.hub` value in it's WHERE statement.

Comment: Thanks, But I cannot access t1.hub inside the left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

In TD14.10 you can utilize `LAST_VALUE` to access data from the "last" row. The `CASE`s are based on your query:

```
SELECT
   t2.ID, 
   CASE WHEN t1.Hub = t2.Hub THEN t2.Hub END AS Original_Hub, 
   CASE WHEN t1.Hub = t2.Hub THEN t2.Status END AS Original_Status, 
   -- get the last Hub
   LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN t1.Hub <> t2.Hub AND Table2.Status like 'Found%'
                   THEN t2.Hub
              END)
   OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.Hub = t2.Hub THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, t2.TS 
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Derived_Hub,
   -- get the last Status
   LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN t1.Hub <> t2.Hub AND Table2.Status like 'Found%'
                   THEN t2.Status
              END)
   OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.Hub = t2.Hub THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, t2.TS
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Derived_Status
FROM
    Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2
    ON (t1.ID=t2.ID)  
QUALIFY
   ROW_NUMBER () -- return the 1st row only
   OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.Hub = t2.Hub THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, t2.TS) = 1
```

EXPLAIN should combine all `OVER` into a single STATS-step as they use the same `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY`.